# Prove that: If there exists $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $f'(a) > 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f$ be differentiable in $\mathbb R$, with $f'$ differentiable and $f'(x) \geq 0,f''(x) \geq 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb R$.

How do I rigorously prove that (using Lagranges Mean Value Theorem):

If there exists $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $f'(a) > 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$

I know that if f is monotonic increasing and $f'>m>0$ for $x>a$ (where $f'(a)=m>0$) then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) > \lim_{x \to \infty} mx = \infty$

But I want something more rigorouse.

Thanks for any idea or direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $f$ tends to $\infty$ is rigorously written as follows : $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)= \infty  \iff \forall N > 0 \space \exists \space  M(N) > 0 \space |\space  x>M \Rightarrow  f(x) > N$

Lagrange Mean Value Theorem ensures that in the conditions specified by the question it's $\forall \space a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a<b, \space \exists \space c \in (a,b) \space | \space f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} > 0 $

then choosing as $N=f(a)$, since both $f'(c)>0$ and $(b-a)>0$, it's

$f(b)=f'(c)(b-a)+f(a)> f(a)=N $

and so picking $a<\frac{b+a}{2}:=M(N)<b$ it's true that $b>M \Rightarrow f(b)>N$. Then for the condition below it's

$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)= \infty $

Answer (score 2):

For $x >a$ there exists $t$ in $(a,x)$ with $f(x)-f(a)=(x-a)f'(t)$ so $f(x)-f(a) \geq (x-a)f'(a) \to \infty$.  [I have used the fact that $f'$ is increasing since its derivative is non-negative].

Answer (score 1):

Another approch is to note that $f'(x) \geq f'(a) >0$ for all $x\geq a$ because $f''$ is non-negative. Thus $f$ is strictly increasing in $[a, \infty) $.

It follows that either $f(x) \to L$ or $f(x) \to \infty $ as $x\to\infty $. But if $f(x) \to L$ then (via LMVT) $f' (c) =f(x+1)-f(x)\to 0$ which contradicts $f'(c) \geq f'(a) >0$. Hence we must have $f(x) \to\infty$.